# How to extend Linux partititon dual booted with Windows? And how to rebuild Grub after extending the partition?

Tags: partition, kali-linux, grub2, gparted, move-partition

I have dual booted Linux(Kali Linux) and Windows, Due to of shortage storage in Linux ,I want to shrink the Windows partition and extend Linux partition

I know there are many posts regarding this, I have checked most of them, But in my case, I have to extend the Linux partition (/dev/sda8) from the start sector, And most the post explains, how to resize the partition, But none of them specify **how to rebuild grub after extending Linux partition**

First Image is the current state of the disk

Second Image is how I want it to extend (From Kali Linux -LIVE USB)

[image: This is current state of disk (Not live)]

[image: This how I want to be (Gparted Live )]

/dev/sda8 ==>> Linux Partition

/dev/sda6 ==>> Window Partition (Drive E:)

I want extend /dev/sda8, Since I am extending it from the right/starting sector , Grub has to be reconfigured right? **How do I  rebuild grub after extending the Linux partition?**

I'm using a distribution of Debian Linux called [`Kali Linux`](https://www.kali.org),below is main information of my laptop which may help.

```
fdisk -l                                 
Disk /dev/sda: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: TOSHIBA MQ04ABF1
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: A60A71DD-D86F-4DB5-9A7A-915AE5991E42

Device          Start        End   Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sda1        2048     534527    532480   260M EFI System
/dev/sda2      534528     567295     32768    16M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3      567296  314778396 314211101 149.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4   314779648  316571647   1792000   875M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5   316571648 1083027455 766455808 365.5G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda6  1134227456 1848948735 714721280 340.8G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda7  1951885312 1953523711   1638400   800M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda8  1848948736 1942423551  93474816  44.6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sda9  1942423552 1951885311   9461760   4.5G Linux swap

Partition table entries are not in disk order.



  df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    udev            1.8G     0  1.8G   0% /dev
    tmpfs           376M  2.0M  374M   1% /run
    /dev/sda8        44G   39G  3.2G  93% /
    tmpfs           1.9G  104M  1.8G   6% /dev/shm
    tmpfs           5.0M  4.0K  5.0M   1% /run/lock
    /dev/sda1       256M   26M  231M  11% /boot/efi
    tmpfs           376M   88K  376M   1% /run/user/0

mount
sysfs on /sys type sysfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
udev on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,nosuid,relatime,size=1880636k,nr_inodes=470159,mode=755)
devpts on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,nosuid,noexec,relatime,gid=5,mode=620,ptmxmode=000)
tmpfs on /run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=384424k,mode=755)
/dev/sda8 on / type ext4 (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro)
securityfs on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
tmpfs on /run/lock type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,size=5120k)
cgroup2 on /sys/fs/cgroup type cgroup2 (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,nsdelegate,memory_recursiveprot)
pstore on /sys/fs/pstore type pstore (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
efivarfs on /sys/firmware/efi/efivars type efivarfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
none on /sys/fs/bpf type bpf (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime,mode=700)
systemd-1 on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type autofs (rw,relatime,fd=29,pgrp=1,timeout=0,minproto=5,maxproto=5,direct,pipe_ino=14743)
mqueue on /dev/mqueue type mqueue (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
debugfs on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
hugetlbfs on /dev/hugepages type hugetlbfs (rw,relatime,pagesize=2M)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
sunrpc on /run/rpc_pipefs type rpc_pipefs (rw,relatime)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
configfs on /sys/kernel/config type configfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
/dev/sda1 on /boot/efi type vfat (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=ascii,shortname=mixed,utf8,errors=remount-ro)
binfmt_misc on /proc/sys/fs/binfmt_misc type binfmt_misc (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime)
tmpfs on /run/user/0 type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,size=384420k,nr_inodes=96105,mode=700)
gvfsd-fuse on /run/user/0/gvfs type fuse.gvfsd-fuse (rw,nosuid,nodev,relatime,user_id=0,group_id=0)
tracefs on /sys/kernel/debug/tracing type tracefs (rw,nosuid,nodev,noexec,relatime


cat /etc/fstab
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda8 during installation
UUID=c1b32d6c-34a5-4628-b126-862be53fc9de /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=E06C-6211  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda9 during installation
UUID=9a8a2b86-53c5-4667-8e07-9e4304a2191d none            swap    sw              0       0
```

Comment: First have good backups of all systems. Only use Windows to shrink NTFS partitions & reboot immediately & run chkdsk on the NTFS partitions you edit. Then from live installer or gparted live ISO, use gparted to move Linux partition left and expand right. If not changing partitions, you typically do not have to reinstall grub. But have live installer handy just in case and know how to add Boot-Repair or manually chroot into system to make repairs.  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Comment: @oldfred   Thanks , Can you check this video? (https://youtu.be/1QjQ4q5kcVs?t=674) from time 11:14, Is he reinstalling grub is correct way ? Can you please verify it?, I know Boot-Repair is a better option. But I would like to learn what I am doing, I would consider Boot-Repair as my last resort.I have installed Boot-Repair in Live just  if anything goes wrong.

Comment: Looks like he is doing the full chroot method. UEFI chroot, must include ESP - efi system partition
http://askubuntu.com/questions/53578/can-i-install-in-uefi-mode-with-the-alternate-installer/57380#57380  chroot with UEFI, LVM, encryption on NVMe drive
https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2349833&p=13602088#post13602088 To chroot, you need the same 32bit or 64 bit kernel. Best to use same version.
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BasicChroot If you can boot with rEFInd or Supergrub, you can just reinstall from within your install.

Comment: @oldfred So to sum everything are these the commands I should run  `sudo mount /dev/sda8 /mnt            #Mount root (/) partition 
sudo mkdir -p /mnt/boot/efi          #Create EFI partition mount point
sudo mount /dev/sda1 /mnt/boot/efi   #Mount EFI partition  
sudo mount --bind /dev /mnt/dev 
sudo mount --bind /proc /mnt/proc 
sudo mount --bind /sys /mnt/sys   
chroot /mnt/ '/bin/bash    
grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg  
grub-install /dev/sda`

Comment: The full grub install also runs the update to grub.cfg.